# Locking an IPython notebook for editing

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have IPython notebooks running on a server, and I'm editing/prototyping them locally.  I use rsync to push my local notebooks when I'm ready to show them to others.

Problem is, with all these notebooks open, it's easy to accidentally edit things on the server notebooks instead of the local ones.  Is there some reasonable mechanism to prevent accidental editing of notebooks?  I still want to be able to run the server-notebooks, and they still should be able to write output - I just want to somehow lock them so they can't be edited.

Comment: Did someone try https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Readonly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the notebook permissions to be read-only by opening a new Terminal directly in your Jupyter server.